# Javascript Manual Selection doesn't replace

Tags: javascript, replace, selection

I have some text in a textbox. I automatically select some of it by calling textbox.setSelectionRange(a, b). But then, when I start typing again, the letters are appended on the right of the selection instead of replacing the selected text. Is there any way I can make the selection 'replaceable' by the user?
edit: it seems that if you execute the function twice on the same piece of text, the text doesn't replace any more. So that's what happened

Comment: This works fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/BXT5v/.

Comment: @pimvdb Yeah, it selects text, but when you are already focused and you call that method, the selected text won't be replaced when you type further.

Comment: This fiddle executes `setSelectionRange` when you focus the textbox, but it still works fine on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/BXT5v/2/. What browser are you using?

Comment: @pimvdb It works in firefox as well... curious. what does get(0) do?

Comment: That's just jQuery, `$('input').get(0)` returns the input element, just like `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`.

Comment: @pimvdb It had something to do with selecting twice, I think. Fixed it now. Thanks for the help! ^_^

Comment: @niomaster Post the solution as an answer, and accept it. If you don't consider your question/answer to be useful, delete the question.